# execvpe argv to parameter matching syntax help needed

Tags: c, parameters, argv, execvp

I get "passing argument 2 of ‘execvp’ from incompatible pointer type" and
 expected ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘const char **’
I'm wondering what the correct syntax is? Thanks!

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  if(argv[0]!=NULL)
    return -1;
  int pid = fork();
  if(pid==0)
    execvp(argv[0],argv+strlen(argv[0]));
  else
    wait();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` functions don't accept `const char*`. In your case, simply change `argv` to `char*`, that's the correct prototype.

Btw. `argv + strlen(argv[0])` doesn't make any sense, what did you mean by that?

Comment: Great! Just deleting const seems to have fixed it! However, if I run it with say emacs, it doesn't actually load it.

Comment: Actually, the `execl` family does accept `char const*`, but the `execv` variants don't. @Josh: `const char* argv[]` isn't standard C anyway.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: yes it is. They're exactly the same.

Comment: @Josh Most likely because `argv + strlen(argv[0])` doesn't make any sense did you mean `argv+1`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I think it's supposed to be execvp(argv[1],argv+2); since argv[0] is ./a.out and arv[1] is emacs and the rest are any args given, but that doesn't work either

Comment: @Let_Me_Be what does argv+1 actually mean? Is it passing argv[1] through arv[n]?

Comment: @Josh `argv+1` is `&argv[1]`. Because `a[b]` is defined as `*(a+b)`